# How to change owner or group when syncing with rsync in vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, rsync, vagrant-windows

Currently I'm struggling with permission issues in my Drupal installation on a [Drupal-VM](https://www.drupalvm.com/) (Vagrant + Virtual Box on Windows). I'm syncing with rsync which leads to owner and group `vagrant` of synced files and folders. Because apache is running with user `www-data` files cannot be written in in the public temp folder `sites/default/files`, which is owned by `vagrant:vagrant`. That's why I'm trying to change the group of synced files to `www-data`. How do I accomplish this?

#### My Environment

Vagrant 1.9.1
VirtualBox 5.1.14 r112924

#### My OS

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

#### Summary

I've already tried the following settings in `config.yml`:

`vagrant_synced_folders:
  - local_path: C:\#\myproject
    destination: /var/www/myproject.dev
    type: rsync
    create: true
    options_override:
      group: www-data`

or

`vagrant_synced_folders:
  - local_path: C:\#\myproject
    destination: /var/www/myproject.dev
    type: rsync
    create: true
    group: www-data`

These don't take effect after `vagrant reload`. When I check `.vagrant/machines/mydrupalvmbox/virtualbox/syncedfolders` `group` is still `vagrant`. Changing the group in this temp file and doing a `vagrant rsync` results the correct group for rsynced files and directories. But after `vagrant reload` those temp settings are gone and group `vagrant` is back again.

I've also tried to change the group via `rsync_args` with no success:

`vagrant_synced_folders:
  - local_path: C:\#\myproject
    destination: /var/www/myproject.dev
    type: rsync
    create: true
   options_override:
     rsync__args: [
       "--verbose", "--archive", "--delete",
       "--chmod=gu=rwX,o=rX",
       "--group", # required for the following command
       "--groupmap=*:www-data"
     ]`

I get an error: `Error: rsync: --groupmap=*:www-data: unknown option`.

So what's the right setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Drupal VM](https://www.drupalvm.com/) you have to use `rsync__group` inside of `options_override`:

```
vagrant_synced_folders:
  - local_path: C:\#\myproject
  // [...]
  options_override:
    rsync__group: www-data
```

See related issue: https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/1199

This might work in other vagrant boxes too.

Answer (score 1):

which version of `rsync` are you running ?

The `groupmap` option has been included in version 3.1.0 (see https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.0-NEWS)

> ```
> - Added the --usermap/--groupmap/--chown options for manipulating file
>   ownership during the copy.
> ```

upgrade your rsync version (if you're using cygwing, upgrade cygwin/rsync) and make sure you get an up-to-date version

```
rsync --version
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.8, so I will try to update. But the rsync__args way seems to complicated. Is there a way to set the general vagrant `group` setting for rsync? Because when I fill in the target group in `.vagrant/machines/mydrupalvmbox/virtualbox/syncedfolders`, files are synced with the right group.